# Div stuck on left side of mobile view, and message box isnt inline with input boxes

Tags: html, css, centering

[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgUHG.png)
[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IinvV.png)

Honestly have no idea what to do anymore. I feel like it should be easier than I'm making it out to be.
Id love to share my code but its a lot

Comment: Code here: https://github.com/jtkandrews/FirstWebsite.git

Comment: After the div becomes less than 600px it no longer becomes centered

Answer (score 0):

make sure other atributtes that you gave like margin is not zero

Comment: I havent set anything to none. If that what zero would entail

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).